# manually re evaluate expressions in asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, translation, expressionbuilder

We are doing translations with a custom expression builder in our application. The chosen language is saved in the session. The actual translations get loaded in the application cache when it first starts.
We are using .NET 3.5/c#

the whole thing looks like this (example)

```
<asp:MenuItem Text="<%$Trans:TEXT_MENU_ABOUT_US %>" Value="AboutUs" NavigateUrl="#">
```

Now a user has the possibility to change the language, normally this is not a problem. He just clicks the desired language and the page gets reloaded with the new language.
However, a user can, while purchasing stuff, login and get his language. I can not just reload the current page because it's in the middle of the purchasing process)

Unfortunately all expressions have already been evaluated prior to setting the language (on a simple click event of the login button), so the user doesn't get his language until he navigates to the next step of the purchasing process.

Is it somehow possible to tell the current page to re-evaluate all expressions to reflect the newly chosen language?

thanks for your time

Comment: try using `server.transfer` to the same page. On differet note, typically, you should change the culture/UI Culture very early in page life-cycle (perhaps by working directly with `Request` object) - that way, you can avoid refreshing the page to reflect the new language.

Comment: Sorry, for not responding earlier.
The project/change got postponed and I couldn't really test it. But I keep your advise in mind.
Thanks